# Get base path in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

My project is under `/var/www/Working-copy/`

`mysite` is my project.

Now My problem is that when i use `base_path` it gives me

```
/var/www/Working-copy/mysite/
```

But i want only `/Working-copy/mysite/`. i am using `base_path` under `/resources/views/company/view.blade.php`. I want to use laravel functions. so is there any function available like base_path? I search for it, i can't find proper resource.

Comment: But... `/Working-copy/mysite/` is an invalid path. This doesn't make any sense.

Comment: my project is under www then in Working-copy folder. and i want this path for image viewing. when i use base_path my images not shown. i required `/Working-copy/mysite/`

Comment: You should be storing images like `/var/www/Working-copy/mysite/public/images/foo.jpg`. In which case your view should simply use `<img src=/images/foo.jpg'>`.

Comment: yes you are right. but i am storing images under `/var/www/Working-copy/mysite/uploads/foo.jpg`. so if i use `<img src=/uploads/foo.jpg'>` images are not shown.

Comment: Yeah, your images have to be inside the `/public` directory to be accessible from a web browser. `/uploads` can only be accessed server side from your PHP scripts.

Comment: ohkk.. let me try in your way.. :)

Comment: i try in your way. `/public/uploads/foo.jpg`. and `<img src="/uploads/foo.jpg">`. still images are not shown. is there something missing?

Comment: Sounds like your site configuration is wonky. What's the url you use to load the homepage of your Laravel app?

Comment: `http://localhost:83/Working-copy/mysite/public/` and for other like company `http://localhost:83/Working-copy/mysite/public/company/view`

Comment: Well first of all, I suggest fixing that. Normally you want the homepage of your Laravel app to be accessible at `http://localhost:83` plain and simple. That's where it'll ultimately be when you publish this app on a real hosting server.

Comment: yes you are correct. but if i set `http://localhost:83/mysite/public/` then also not accessible. Network error `http://localhost:83/mysite/public/company/uploads/foo.jpg`. this is taking wrong url.

Comment: You want your apache/nginx document root to map to your 'public' directory. Such that `http://localhost:83` loads the Laravel homepage and `http://localhost:83/company/view` loads your custom route. Then `http://localhost:83/images/foo.jpg` will also work.

Comment: Hey @jszobody i got answer. i use `<img src="{{ url($row->image_path) }}" >` and it works.. :) thanks for your response.